# vb.net how to make a program scans working injectors

Tags: vb.net

i need to write program , to scan or check if any injector program is Working in the computer and stop it in vb.net what can i do?
and this program is hidden and i need my program to work in the background

> vb.net

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is a QA site and you did not ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all running processes, if the process is found do ...

```
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If p.ProcessName = "Process you don't want here." Then
            'Do stuff
        End If
    Next
```